# how to import an extra python package while using pyspark shell

Tags: python, pyspark, airflow

I need to import airflow library modules in Pyspark shell. I am including the module path in --py-files while logging in to Pyspark shell.

```
pyspark2 --py-files /nas/isg_prodops_work/ABO/abound/prod/anaconda/envs/nas_airflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow
```

But, still I am get the following error:

```
>>> from airflow.models import Variable
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named airflow.models
```

The directory structure of my module looks like this:

```
airflow
|-- __init__.py
|-- dag(directory)
|-- operators(directory)
|-- models.py
```

Comment: It seems you just wrote the path of the `py` file. you have to add the file name in the end of your path. `pyspark2 --py-files /nas/isg_prodops_work/ABO/abound/prod/anaconda/envs/nas_airflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/models.py`

Comment: I tried adding the py file also. That did not work either

Comment: You have a `.py` that contains `pyspark` code and you want to run it with an additional `.py` file in your linux terminal, is that right?

Comment: I need to import an entire package. The package has the .py file in it. Even if I include the .py file path directly its not importing.

Comment: I've written an answer. please check that out!

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
pyspark2 --py-files /nas/isg_prodops_work/ABO/abound/prod/anaconda/envs/nas_airflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/models.py
```

and then import like this:

```
>>> from models import Variable
```

Comment: This is still giving ImportError: No module named models error

Comment: Try with `pyspark` instead of `pyspark2`.